# syntax Error/bad SQL grammar in Build time

Tags: mysql, oracle

This is my query I am using in my java file. I tried it in Oracle SQL developer it works as expected. But I am getting an error in build time.

```
 private static final String FIND_TOTALS_BY_STATUS_FOR_HEADER = "SELECT status, count(status) FROM uh_task_executions t1 WHERE th_task_execution_header_id_fk = ?"
        + "AND start_time IN  (SELECT start_time FROM uh_task_executions t2 WHERE th_task_execution_header_id_fk = ? and t1.target = t2.target) GROUP BY status";
```

Script:

```
SELECT status, count(status) FROM uh_task_executions t1 WHERE th_task_execution_header_id_fk = 10047
AND start_time IN  (SELECT start_time FROM uh_task_executions t2 WHERE th_task_execution_header_id_fk = 10047 and t1.target = t2.target) GROUP BY status
```

Error Message

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT status,
>   count(status) FROM uh_task_executions t1 WHERE
>   th_task_execution_header_id_fk = ? AND start_time IN  (SELECT
>   start_time FROM uh_task_executions t2 WHERE
>   th_task_execution_header_id_fk = ? and t1.target = t2.target) GROUP BY
>   status];  nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your **SQL syntax**; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'start_time IN  (SELECT start_time FROM uh_task_executions t2
>   WHERE th_task_execu' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add space, here:

```
+ " AND start_time IN ...
   ^
   |
  here
```

Also, you'd rather use table aliases **everywhere**, otherwise you might get unexpected results.